# How to call function only once in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have function call (pop view) in my 1st view controller which have to be called only once in app. Since then whenever I return back to 1st View controller the function need not to be called again.

```
func popView() {
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popView") as! popView
        self.addChild(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
```

I have tried the following code and previous other sources in stack overflow, didn't work though..

```
 ///// Once Action in View Controller
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if self.isBeingPresented || self.isMovingToParent {
         // Perform an action that will only be done once
             popView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you using to return to first view controller??

Comment: save flag in userdefaults -> isPopOverVCPopped -> true/false.if it false then pop it and update isPopOverVCPopped as true.

Comment: @ Jarvis The Avenger, I am using  let ViewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController") as UIViewController
        self.present(ViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: @Sakshi, could you please explain as code...I tried but something is missing

Comment: @AzeemRiverswave I have posted code, plz check it.Let me know if any issues are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call that PopView function only once in your App then try this,

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     showPopUp()
 }

func showPopUp() {
        let showPop: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showPop")
        if showPop == false {
            // don't show ----Pop
        } else {
           openPop()
           UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "showPop")
        }
        
 }
```

This will call the pop up only once in app life cycle...

Comment: `private var isShowPop = Bool.self`?? It's not even used.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this works. In your ViewController, add a static property:

```
    static var shouldPop = true

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if isBeingPresented || isMovingToParent {
         // Perform an action that will only be done once
             if (type(of: self).shouldPop) {
                 type(of: self).shouldPop = false
                 popView()
             }
        }
    }
```

Of course, depending on your setup, this won't work if you have more than one instance of this viewcontroller that should keep their own state on whether popView should be called or not.

Comment: There is two option for this solution `static var` and `var` depending on business logic.

Answer (score 2):

You should call this in viewDidLoad method. It's called once per UIViewController life cycle. 
Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload).

Just like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.isBeingPresented || self.isMovingToParent {
     // Perform an action that will only be done once
         popView()
    }
}
```

If your way is pop view after you was once in view controller you could do like this:

```
    /// bool that help indicate your visit 
    var isViewControllerVisited = false 

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if isViewControllerVisited {
         // Perform an action that will only be done once
             popView()
        }

        //change it here
        isViewControllerVisited = true 
    }
```

Hope it's help!

Comment: I have tried in viewdidload its still has not effect...didnt work

Comment: @AzeemRiverswave Are your sure your code inside If statement called?

Comment: @AzeemRiverswave If you want popView when just return back to controller i recommend use some bool global variable to identify that you was in this controller, then call it inside viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

For me I prefer to use lazy loading. This allow not to write any logic, just need to use Swift lazy var declaration. Something like this:

```
private lazy var viewDidAppearOnce: Bool = {
    popView()
}()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    _ = viewDidAppearOnce
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the view controller's lifecycle, the `viewDidLoad` method only gets called once. so you should call your method only there.

Or you can try the following code:

```
var isScreenAppeared = false

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if !isScreenAppeared {
         popView()
    }
    isScreenAppeared = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code, try it..

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isPopOverVCPopped")

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isPopOverVCPopped") == false {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isPopOverVCPopped")

        popView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You set flag just before checking for its value.